# Understanding how queries work

Tags: sql

I have the following schema:

- Movies (title, year, length, genre, studioName, producerC#)
- StarsIn (movieTitle, movieYear, starName)
- MovieStar (name, address, gender, birthdate)
- MovieExec (name, address, cert#, netWorth)
- Studio (name, address, presC#)

Who were the male stars in the 2009 movie avatar?

Let's get rid of the gender aspect of the query, so it's reduced to who were the stars in the 2009 movie avatar?

```
Select x StarName  
From StarsIn x    
Where  x.movieTitle='avatar'   
       x.movieYear=2009;
```

I am having a rough time joining two tables. How would you address the gender aspect of this query?

Who is the president of MGM?

```
Select e.Name  
FROM MovieExec e, Studio St  
where St.name='MGM'
      AND st.presC#=e.cert#;
```

Solution to eldest problem.

```
Select x.StarName    
FROM StarsIn x, MovieStar y   
where y.gender = 'Male'
     AND x.movieTitle = 'avatar' 
     AND x.movieYear = 2009  
     AND  x.starName = y.name;
```

Comment: This is extremely basic SQL.  Please go review a few tutorials.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Eventually every concept becomes "extremely" basic once you understand it. This is not homework. This is an example from the slides that I am trying to understand.  @dfundako

Comment: The query is invalid, string constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL, double quotes are for identifiers. `"avatar"` is a column name, `'avatar'` is a strings

Comment: are you sure these tables do not have any ID columns, or did you simplify the structure for us?

Comment: That's the way they are provided in the slides.

Comment: Both queries you show use the old 1980s syntax (made redundant in 1992 by introducing explicit ANSI joins in the SQL standard papers). This should not be taught anymore. (Or only in the sense of: "I am showing you how they did it in the early days of relational databases, so you understand old queries when you see them.")

Comment: It's also a good rule to only select from the table(s) you want to see data from. In the second query you want data from `MovieExec` only. You also want a matching `Studio` record to *exist*, but that would best be placed in `WHERE` with `EXISTS` or `IN`. (Same goes for the first query of course: `where starname in (select name from moviestar where gender = 'm')`.) Sometimes, however, you'd still decide for a join, particularily when you think it likely that you might want to change that query some day and add columns from the other table to your select list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic query you have show is wrong to begin with. You can't use the table alias as a column in the select list. The Select `x StarName` is wrong. I assume you want to see the column starname, so you need to specify that as `x.starname`.

You also can't just list conditions in the `where` clause. Multiple conditions must be combined with `and` or `or`. In your case this should be an `and`.

So the basic query from your question should be:

```
select x.starname
from StarsIn x    
where x.movieTitle = 'avatar'   
  and x.movieYear = 2009;
```

Joining tables is done in the `from` clause using the `JOIN` keyword, with the join condition defined with the `ON` keyword which should compare the columns from both tables that contain the same values. This is typically the primary key column of one table and a corresponding foreign key column from the other.

In your example I assume that `starsin.starname` matches `MovieStar.name` so the join condition should be between those two columns:

```
select x.starname 
from StarsIn x    
  JOIN moviestar m ON x.starname = m.name --<< this is the  JOIN
where x.movieTitle = 'avatar'   
  and x.movieYear = 2009
  and m.gender = 'male';
```

Comment: Hello @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you so much for your clear and constructive answer. How would you do this query without using the JOIN word. I am thinking of creating two tuple variables.

Comment: @TheMathNoob: there is a way to join tables without the JOIN keyword, but I strongly believe that should not be used, so I am not going to tell you.

Comment: I understand. I have been learning SQL a few weeks ago and the professor hasn't gone over JOIN yet. I am pretty sure he addressed this question without using the JOIN word.

Comment: Then tell him he is still using a syntax that was replaced with the "modern" JOIN keywords over 30 years ago

Comment: I am gonna show you another query and will give you the exact same solution provided by the professor.

Comment: @TheMathNoob This is outdated syntax used instead of `join`. Use join if you are allowed to. It separates joins from criteria, and this improves greatly the readability of a query, and also helps avoid silly mistakes like not performing join at all.

Comment: Yes I will use JOIN for sure, but I want to understand the way to do it with the old sintax as well. I will post my solution with the old sintax and you tell me if it's wrong.